# Predicate Logic - Logic to English Translation

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

I have a Predicate Logic question that looks like this:

**Q5. Let S  and T be two sequences of Natural numbers and let P be the predicate:**

> $∃ i : 1 ≤ i ≤ size(S). ∀ j : 1 ≤ j ≤ size(S). ∀ k : 1 ≤ k ≤ size(T). S[i] ≥ S[j] ∧ S[i] ≤ T [k]$

Here's the list of possible answers:

```
A.  S=[1,8,12]  T=[1,8,11]
B.  S=[1,8,11]  T=[14]
C.  S=[92,17]  T=[1,8,11]
D.  S=[1,19,62,34,83]  T=[23,96,102]
```

The correct answer is B. Can someone please explain why this is? Can someone also please explain, am I correct or incorrect in assuming that `S[i]≥S[j]` is redundant because the values in S will also be greater than or equal to themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't state the actual question, but I assume the question is: for which of the following pairs of $S$ and $T$ is the predicate $P$ true?

OK, $P$ is saying that there needs to be some number from $S$ that is greater or equal to any of the numbers of $S$, and also smaller or equal to any of the numbers in $T$.  So effectively this means: the highest number in $S$ needs to be smaller than the smallest number in $T$ (since being the highest number in $S$ means it is greater or equal to all numbers in $S$, and being smaller than the smallest number in $T$ means it is smaller than all numbers in $T$)

This rules out A (12 is not smaller than any number in $T$), C (92 is not smaller than any number in $T$), and $D$ (83 is not smaller than 23).

But, B is ok: 11 is smaller than 14.

And no, the $S[i]\geq S(j]$ is not redundant: you are looking for some i such that for all j: $S[i]\geq S(j]$, and that is only true when $S[i]$ is the highest number in $S$ ... if it said that for some (or for all) i there is *some* j such that $S[i]\geq S(j]$, then you would be right, since you can always pick j to be i, but it says that it should work for *all* j.